# Use the tag of UIButton in the prepare segue

Tags: swift, segue, sender

I have a button that after tapping, perform a segue, in this perform, I send the tag of UIButton, with the sender

```
@IBAction func nextBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "more", sender: sender.tag)
}
```

and in the prepare segue, I try to use this tags, but appearntly i am doing it wrong

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "more" {
        if let navigationVC = segue.destination as? UINavigationController, let openPDF = navigationVC.topViewController as? Morepage {
            let senderTag = (sender as? UIButton)?.tag
                if senderTag == 1 {
                  print(123)
                } else if senderTag == 2 {
                  print(123)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

The `senderTag` is shown as none or nil. could you help me to use sender.tag properly in the prepare segue. 
many thanks

Comment: in function nextBtn(_ sender: UIButton) you should performSegue with sender = sender, not sender.tag

Comment: My advice is to stop using tags. Forget that the property is even there. It's not something that can produce readable code. Anyway the tag can be `nil` only if the `sender` is not a `UIButton`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your button tag following way. `sender:` will be `sender` not `sender.tag`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "more" {
        if let navigationVC = segue.destination as? UINavigationController, let openPDF = navigationVC.topViewController as? Morepage {

                if yourButton.tag == 1 {
                  print(123)
                } else if yourButton.tag == 2 {
                  print(123)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

OR

```
  if sender.tag == 1 {
            print("Button 1 is pressed")
        }
```